# A regular expression that selects the value of a link parameter PHP

Tags: php, regex

How to make a PHP regular expression that select the value of a specific parameter of the link, for example :

`https://anylink.com/?s=a&start=19&info=abc` The regular expression select the value of start parameter ( `19` in this case ) .

I tried with this pattern : `[^start=]+$` but it only selects the the last parameter with `=` sign

Comment: `[^…]` is a negated character class. What inspired you to that regex:? Btw, why not [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) / [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str)?

Comment: I think regular expression will work better for me because I want to replace the parameter, I tried to recreate this regular expression  stackoverflow.com/questions/9703039/regex-for-picking-a-value-after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$subject = 'https://anylink.com/?s=a&start=19&info=abc';
$pattern = '/start=([0-9]+)/';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);

var_dump($tokens);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to do

Comment: I think you should change `[0-9]+` to `[^&]+`, because this way if the parameter gets changed from _integer_ to another type, it will still work.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes That is certainly possible, but questionable. Typically a defined parameter does not suddenly change its type. In contrary, typcially one want's to make really certainly that one get's what one expects :-) So I would advise against it, but this certainly is a question of personal preferences and the situation itself which we do not know.

Comment: I think it could turn into _decimal_ easily. But, it is only a suggest.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes A parameter called `start` most likely refers to either a position in a queue, or an offset or an ID. In all cases an integer is what want to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) for that.

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['start'];
```